# number of events overlapping with date

Tags: python-3.x

I have start and end dates of events and i want to find out events overlapping with the event date.

The input contains only two elements representing the start and end date of an event.

```
intervals=[[29,31],[23,26],[24,25]]
```

The next line of input will have the event date.

```
date=24
```

I am expecting an output should have the number of events overlapping with the event date but not able to get it. Kindly help here.

```
Sample output=2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is to check if `date` is "inside" `interval` (element from `intervals` list), and then count "positive checks":

```
intervals = [[29,31],[23,26],[24,25]]
date = 24
# Mark interval as "1" if date is inside it, than sum "ones"
counter = sum([1 for interval in intervals 
                 if date in range(interval[0], interval[1] + 1)])  

# +1 because range function doesn’t include upper limit in the result
print(counter)  # prints 2
```

Another way to perform "checks" is to use interval comparison:

```
counter = sum([1 for interval in intervals 
                 if interval[0] <= date <= interval[1]])
```